# How to call TransferFrom() NFT contract?

Tags: nft

i'm new and have a question. I am testing after the user approves the setApprovalForAll permission, how do I get my nft with `TransferFrom()` . Thanks, hope someone can help me soon.[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to post the smart contract code here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks, i found the reason